# How to create REST api post request

Tags: php, api, post, postman

I am doing GET request like this:

```
//url = http://localhost/api/login.php/?name=max

if(isset($_GET['name'])){
  echo "Hi ".$_GET['name'];
}else{
  echo "Error";
}
```

But I am unable to fetch data from **POST** request.

```
//url = http://localhost/api/login.php/?name=max

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
  echo "Hi ".$_POST['name'];
}else{
  echo "Error";
}
```

**How can I get post data.**

Comment: That's not how you pass post data.  name is still in the query string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

**[$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)** data is read from the body of the request if the content-type is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.  You can also read the request body via the [php://stdin](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php) stream.

Data is not read from the query string, like **$_GET**.

Answer (score 0):

You cant get `$_POST` data from the url, what you can do is this;

```
<form action="http://localhost/api/login.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="max">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Or if you want people to set their name;

```
<form action="http://localhost/api/login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" value="max">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

It's pretty simple and clear :)